# How to switch between two ImageViews in onClickListener

Tags: android, if-statement, imageview

I have an ImageView and I want to switch between two images in OnClick Listener
For more details: in shared preferences I have a checkbox to enable and disable sound. In a layout i have an image view to handle sound in shared preferences.
this is my code:

```
 imgsound=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgsound);
    imgsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if(Settings.isSoundEnabled(getApplicationContext())){
               imgsound.setImageResource(ic_sound_off);
               setSoundFalse(getApplicationContext());
           }
           if(Settings.isSounddesabled(getApplicationContext())){
               imgsound.setImageResource(ic_sound_on);
               setSoundTrue(getApplicationContext());
           }
       }
   });
```

The first `if` statement works well and the image turns to `ic_sound_off` and the sound is disabled, but when I click again to enable sound and turn image to `ic_sound_on` it doesn't work

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but did you perhaps mean to write "Settings.isSoundDisabled" ? Both for the capitol "D" and the correct spelling of disabled.

Comment: It's more concise to use `else` instead of the second if. That would also fix your typo (as mentioned by Emily).

Comment: Christine :) yes i fix it with else , i make a stupid error :D :D